# Get input field text/value from external HTML and refresh at a set interval

Tags: html, jquery

I am having some difficulties in getting text from a url and assigning the retrieved data into a form input field. When I use a div the code works but i want to use an input text field.

Below is my jQuery:

```
     <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#torefresh").load("myurl.php");
        setInterval(function() {
            $("#torefresh").load("myurl.php");
        }, 100);
    });
    
    </script>
```

This is my html:

```
   <div data-value="" id='torefresh'></div>
```

It works with the above div.

```
    <input type='text'  readonly="readonly" name='torefresh' id='torefresh'>
```

But i want the input text solution

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the jQuery `.load()` [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/load/):

> jQuery uses the browser's .innerHTML property to parse the retrieved document and insert it into the current document.

However, the `input` element doesn't have an innerHTML property - you must use the value property (or `.val()` in jQuery-ese).  Therefore, you cannot use `.load()` to do this.

Since `.load()` is just a shorthand for `$.ajax()`, you can use that instead.

Try:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
   get_new_data();
   setInterval(function() {
       get_new_data();
   }, 100);
});
function get_new_data(){
   $.ajax({
      type: 'get',
       url: 'myurl.php'
   }).done((retn) => {
      $('#torefresh').val(retn);
   });
}
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, you have provided the solution that i was looking for!! have a good day

Comment: when i try to insert the value into db its directing to 'myurl.php'  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { $pid=$_POST['torefresh'];  $sql=mysqli_query($con,"insert into tblP (pcode) values('$pid') ");  header('location: add-pc.php'); }

Comment: sorry my form had an action directing to myurl.php so its okay thanks once again

Comment: Glad you sorted it out, and thank you for sharing the solution to your comment/question.  *Meilleurs voeux with your project, and Meilleurs voeux this Christmas season*